# How to restart the connection in postgres?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, pg

I am using pg for node JS application, after restart postgres I anew create client. 
But after restarting postgres no queries are executed.
The only thing found was a link to github. Not help. What could be the problem?

https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/1558

```
   const { Client: pgClient } = require('pg');
```

```
...restart() {
   this.db = new pgClient({
      host: ...,
      port: ...,
      database: ...,
      user: ...,
      password: ...
   });

   this.db.connect()
      .then(() => {
          ...
      })
      .catch((err) => {
          ...
      })  

    this.db.on('error', (err) => {
      this.db.query('SELECT NOW() as now')
         .then(() => {
             ...
         })
         .catch(e => {
             ...
            setTimeout(...restart.bind(this), 1000);
         })
    })
}
```

```
...methodQuery = function() {      
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.db.query('SELECT NOW() as now')
         .then(() => {
            resolve()
         })
         .catch((err) => {
            reject(err) 
         })
   }).then(() => {
      ...
   });
};
```

Comment: Do you get any errors? Do the queries just hang, and never finish?

Comment: there is a complex system: there is a handler. It constantly calls this query method to postgres.
But the query in the method is not executed

Comment: `this.db.query` is called? If so, the promise should either be resolved or rejected - which one is it?

Comment: rejected. Always after restart

Comment: and what is the error you are receiving when it is rejected?

Comment: Why don't you just use the `Pool`? It will create a new connection for you automatically. And then you do not need to do manual `connect()`.

Comment: Error: Client has encountered a connection error and is not queryable